# JSON Parser error

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the json parser from json.org to handle data from my application. The problem is that the parser cannot handle some json formats.

One request receives the data below.

```
  <?php

  $obj = array("cities"=>array("city1","city2","city3","city4","city5"));

  echo json_encode($obj);

  ?>
```

Results in the json below

```
{
"cities": ["city1","city2","city3","city4","city5"] 
}
```

the code below handles the above data

```
  var data = json_parse(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText, function (key, value){

  alert(key +' = '+value);

  });
```

The parser fails and throws an error.

Does anyone know how to handle such an object.

Comment: Please always, always include the exact error message!

Comment: You've missed something out from your edit (hint: Pekka is asking for it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I executed the following for a quick test and it seems to work:

```
var text = '{ "cities": ["city1","city2","city3","city4","city5"] }';
var data = json_parse(text, function (key, value){
  document.write(key + ' = ' + value + '<br/>');
});
document.write('result = ' + data);
```

It recursively walks the structure and the result is this:

```
0 = city1
1 = city2
2 = city3
3 = city4
4 = city5
cities = ,,,,
= [object Object]
result = undefined
```

What is in your `XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText` field?

Also, aren't you supposed to return a value from your `function(key, value)`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your keys and values into **double** quotes:

```
{
"cities": ["city1","city2","city3","city4","city5"] 
}
```

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object  or an array. These structures can be nested.

You can use [jsonlint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to validate the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wager that the problem lies in your data.  The `''` before city3 is wrong.

It would help if you include some information on the error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The parser fails because the JSON data is malformed. There are two quotes in front of `city3` and the starting quote for `city4` is missing.

```
{
cities: ['city1','city2','city3','city4','city5'] 
}
```

Are you in control of the code that generates this output? It looks like it's being built by hand, while if possible it should be generated using a JSON library.

PHP example:

```
$output = array(
  'cities' => array('city1', 'city2', 'city3', 'city4', 'city5')
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Output:

```
{"cities":["city1","city2","city3","city4","city5"]}
```

Comment: If u handle that output with the parser as i have done:
json_parse(XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText, function (key, value){

  alert(key +' = '+value);

  })

you dont get the expected result as you would get if you used a 'for in' loop on the object. The expected key returned should be "cities", not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your application's json encoding algorithm.

Since you did't specify the application language, I cannot tell you the exact function/method to use, but I suggest you to use standard json encoding techniques instead reinventing the wheel.

For example in php you can use the `json_encode` standard function of one of the many encoding libraries in the open source world.

Comment: The code is produced by php. If u run the code you will realize that the KEYs are indexes.  

Expected result: alert('cities' = [object]);